# In Python, are multiple return values in a function sent as an implicit list?

Tags: python

I am a C programmer trying to learn Python - still a newbie.

```
def fx(x, y):
    return x, y

a, b = fx(1, 2)
```

fx() must be returning x and y as part of a data structure - perhaps a list or a tuple. Exactly what it is I need to know.

Thanks for any inputs,
Manish Jain

Comment: If you want this to be a list, just change your return statement ```return [x, y]``` Could change the return to any data structure by just building the desired structure in the code.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as multiple return values in Python, and nothing is happening implicitly. You are constructing a tuple and returning it. `x, y` is a valid expression creating a 2-tuple. If you don't believe me, open up a Python REPL and type `1, 2`; you'll get the tuple `(1, 2)` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

It is a tuple, and to verify this for yourself you can just do:

```
a = fx(1, 2)
print(type(a))
```

Outputs:

`<class 'tuple'>`

Answer (score 0):

You are making a `tuple` and returning it.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Tuples of two or more items are formed by comma-separated lists of
> expressions.